# Ui-Grid Radio Buttons Selection Per Row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Good Morning All!
I am using Angular ui-Grid.  The last field is supposed to include 3 radio buttons that the user can select per row.  The Default Value on all should be Value=0.  The problem is that I am only able to select 1 radio button in the entire grid rather than one per row.  I believe there should be a way to accomplish this, but I have been unable to figure it out or find any example of such online.  Here is a pic of my grid, it may help to give a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Eventually, the data will come from a call to our Web Api, but currently I am filling the grid with fake data.  Here is my controller code:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {};

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
      {
          name: 'CompanyID', width: '200'
      },
      {
          name: 'CompanyName', width: '200',
      },
      { name: 'City', width: '200' },
      { name: 'State', width: '150' },
      { name: 'Subscription', width: '150' },
      {
          name: 'ReleaseAction', width: '350',
          cellTemplate: '<div ng-init="releaseAction=0"><input name="Release" ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" value="0" style="width:20px">&nbsp;None&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Release" type="radio" ng-model="releaseAction"  value="1" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Accept&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Release" type="radio" ng-model="releaseAction"  value="2" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Decline</div>'
      },

        ]
    };

    var gridData = [
        {
            CompanyID: 1,
            CompanyName: 'Tanner & Associates',
            City: 'Houston',
            State: 'TX',
            Subscription: 'Expired',
            //ReleaseAction: 0
        },
        {
            CompanyID: 2,
            CompanyName: 'Total Energy Services',
            City: 'Conroe',
            State: 'TX',
            Subscription: 'Active'
        },
        {
            CompanyID: 3,
            CompanyName: 'SPSD Inc',
            City: 'Arlington',
            State: 'TX',
            Subscription: 'Active'

        }
    ];

    $scope.gridOptions.data = gridData;
```

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: i think you have to use **btn-group** of bootstrap3

Comment: Thanks for your help, but changing the div class to btn-group does not make a difference in the ui-grid because it sees ALL of the buttons in the grid as 1 group rather than 1 group per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by removing name="Release" from each button.  The new cell template looks like this:

```
  cellTemplate: '<div class="btn-group" ng-init="releaseAction=0"><input ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" value="0" style="width:20px">&nbsp;None&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" value="1" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Accept&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" value="2" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Decline</div>'
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the name is same across all the radio buttons. So, one work-around will be appending the index of each row to the name.

Here is the plucker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/VXpWT8MYwp9bNfF11vHM?p=preview

cellTemplate:

```
<div ng-init="releaseAction=0"><input name="Release{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}" ng-model="releaseAction" type="radio" ng-value="0" style="width:20px">&nbsp;None&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Release{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}" type="radio" ng-model="releaseAction"  ng-value="1" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Accept&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Release{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}" type="radio" ng-model="releaseAction"  ng-value="2" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Decline</div>
```